# Accessing wifi info with RSSI in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi

I am well aware that Apple has not exposed any api's to fetch nearby WiFi access-points and display them as a list for the user to choose with the RSSI signal strength.
There are several hidden and private api's available which does help in finding the WiFi Hotspots nearby the iPhone , but I read that if we use them our app will be outright rejected from Apple Appstore. 
NEHotSpotHelper from NetworkExtension framework also will not fit to my use case.

So I was wondering how it is implemented when I came across the **Qardio Scale** app in appstore which helps the user to identify and fetch nearby wifi hotspots and allows the user to choose one so that the qardio scale can connect into.

Comment: here the link to the health app which does access wifi hotspots https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qardio-heart-health/id855275752?mt=8

Comment: In my project, the `IoT device` collect WiFi info, including `RSSI`, and transfer those data back to iOS App.

Comment: Thanks @AechoLiu, do you think here also qardio  has the feature available in hardware to fetch the Wifi Info and transferring those information to iPhone  through  BLE?

Comment: I don't know about qardio app. But in my projects, one fetchs wifi info through BLE, and another  one fetch wifi info by a middle server, which is responsible to communicate device and app.